# Best way to get input for python script from phone

Tags: python, user-input

I am writing a few interactive python scripts to manage some things. At the moment I am getting all of my commands from the console using `input()`, but in the future it would be nice to enter the commands with my phone when I have no access to my computer. Since I have never worked with something like that I thought it would be easiest to just ask here. I dont need a long explanation, just some tips on finding the right tools to start with.
I already worked with telegram bots, but I thought there must be some simpler way than that.

**In short:** I am searching for the easiest way to get input in a script from a phone.

The scripts look somewhat like this:

```
Class UserInterface:

    def _foo1(self):
        print('foo1')
        
    def _foo2(self):
        print('foo2')
        
    def run(self):
        while True:
            user_input = input('Enter command').lower()
            
            if user_input == 'foo1':
                self._foo1()
            elif user_input == 'foo2':
                self._foo2()
            elif user_input == 'exit':
                print('Exiting.')
                break
            else:
                print('Unknown command')
                
                
if __name__ == '__main__':
    UserInterface().run()
```

Comment: If I get it straight you want to create a python app that can be run on your phone. You can use `kivy + buildozer` or [python-for-android](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), but from experiece, I really do not suggest to do this, because the application building process is a pain in the neck.

Comment: Not quite, I want the script to run on my server and send commands from my phone to the server/script like I would when using `input()`

Comment: Well then you can run a minimal `flask` (or `django` but this is more complex) app on your server side which can do this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to put it in answers but I can't use comments yet. I think you could make easy api with html form and put it on local machine or server. Later just input command into a form on page and fetch answer.

Comment: So you mean making a simple webpage and accessing it via the browser on my phone?

Comment: @JD. Yes just simple webpage